# ASP.net, c#, How to use Global Variable from cookies in sql command

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a sql command. I tested it selecting top 5 to make sure it was connected and mapped to the write datasoure. I can select the top 5. But, when I try to select with the global variable @@HostID I get the error "Must Declare the Scalar Variable". The command executes when the page loads and also when the user changes the value in the dropdownlist. 
I searched for stored procedures and found one that has @HostID nvarchar(50). Is that going to be a parameter source none, cookie, control, form, profile, querystring, session, or routedata.

Visual Studio 2017 Community, Asp.net 4.6, Ado, c#, Microsoft SQL Server 2016

web.config

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceDropDownList" DataTextField="CourseTitle" DataValueField="CourseCode">
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSourceDropDownList" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ICS_NETConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="select distinct sd.scheduledaysid as RecordID,sd.status,sd.minutes,sm.crs_cde as CourseCode,sm.crs_title as CourseTitle,sm.yr_cde,sm.trm_cde,sd.startTime as StartTime,sd.startTime,flt.instrctr_id_num as InstructorID,n.First_Name,n.Last_Name as InstructorName from ics_net.dbo.LMS_ScheduleDays as sd inner join ics_net.dbo.lms_section as s on sd.sectionid = s.SectionID inner JOIN ics_net.dbo.LMS_Course AS c WITH (NOLOCK) ON s.CourseID = c.CourseID inner join tmseprd.dbo.section_master as sm on c.CourseCode + ' ' + s.NAME = sm.crs_cde and left(s.erpcoursekey,4) = sm.yr_cde and substring(s.ERPCourseKey,6,2) = sm.trm_cde inner join tmseprd.dbo.student_crs_hist as sch on sm.crs_cde = sch.crs_cde and sm.yr_cde = sch.yr_cde and sm.trm_cde = sch.trm_cde inner join tmseprd.dbo.faculty_load_table as flt on sm.crs_cde = flt.crs_cde and sm.yr_cde = flt.yr_cde and sm.trm_cde = flt.trm_cde inner join TmsePrd.dbo.NAME_MASTER as n on n.id_num = flt.instrctr_id_num where  sd.startdate &lt;= @Now and sd.enddate &gt;= @Now and flt.INSTRCTR_ID_NUM = @@HostID and sm.crs_cde not like 'ONSO%' or sd.startdate &lt;= dateadd(mi,30,@Now) and sd.enddate &gt;= dateadd(mi,30,@Now) and flt.INSTRCTR_ID_NUM = @@HostID and sm.crs_cde not like 'ONSO%'
    ">
<SelectParameters>
<asp:Parameter DefaultValue="&quot;2019-01-28 15:04:25.493&quot;" Name="Now" />
<asp:Parameter DefaultValue="'49956'" Name="HostID" />
</SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

cs script

```
protected void Page_LoadComplete(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    //MessageBox.Show("You are in the Form.Shown event.");

    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Database.ConnectionString);
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            //SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from courses", con);

            /***** code for current or next session for instructor  *****/
            //Declare @Now2 datetime = current_timestamp,
            //         @HostID2 varchar(15) = '10442'; /*--this would be hostID of the instructor logged into attendance page*/


            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select distinct" +
                " sd.scheduledaysid as RecordID" +
                ",sd.status" +
                ",sd.minutes" +
                ",sm.crs_cde as CourseCode" +
                ",sm.crs_title as CourseTitle" +
                ",sm.yr_cde,sm.trm_cde" +
                ",sd.startTime as StartTime" +
                ",sd.startTime" +
                ",flt.instrctr_id_num as InstructorID" +
                ",n.First_Name" +
                ",n.Last_Name as InstructorName" +
                " from ics_net.dbo.LMS_ScheduleDays as sd" +
                " inner join ics_net.dbo.lms_section as s" +
                " on sd.sectionid = s.SectionID " +
                "inner JOIN ics_net.dbo.LMS_Course AS c " +
                "WITH (NOLOCK) ON s.CourseID = c.CourseID " +
                "inner join tmseprd.dbo.section_master as sm" +
                " on c.CourseCode + ' ' + s.NAME = sm.crs_cde " +
                "and left(s.erpcoursekey,4) = sm.yr_cde " +
                "and substring(s.ERPCourseKey,6,2) = sm.trm_cde " +
                "inner join tmseprd.dbo.student_crs_hist as sch " +
                "on sm.crs_cde = sch.crs_cde " +
                "and sm.yr_cde = sch.yr_cde " +
                "and sm.trm_cde = sch.trm_cde " +
                "inner join tmseprd.dbo.faculty_load_table " +
                "as flt on sm.crs_cde = flt.crs_cde " +
                "and sm.yr_cde = flt.yr_cde " +
                "and sm.trm_cde = flt.trm_cde " +
                "inner join TmsePrd.dbo.NAME_MASTER " +
                "as n on n.id_num = flt.instrctr_id_num " +
                "where  sd.startdate <= @Now and sd.enddate >= @Now " +
                "and flt.INSTRCTR_ID_NUM = @@HostID and sm.crs_cde not like 'ONSO%' " +
                "or sd.startdate <= dateadd(mi,30,@Now) " +
                "and sd.enddate >= dateadd(mi,30,@Now) " +
                "and flt.INSTRCTR_ID_NUM = @@HostID " +
                "and sm.crs_cde not like 'ONSO%'", con);

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RecordID", txtRecordID.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@@HostID", "Int");
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (dr.Read())
            {
                // display data in textboxes
                txtRecordID.Text = dr["RecordID"].ToString();
                txtInstructorID.Text = dr["InstructorID"].ToString();
                txtInstructorName.Text = dr["InstructorName"].ToString();
                txtCourseCode.Text = dr["CourseCode"].ToString();
                txtCourseTitle.Text = dr["CourseTitle"].ToString();
                txtAttendanceCode.Text = dr["AttendanceCode"].ToString();
                btnUpdate.Enabled = true;
            }
            else
            {
                //lblMsg.Text = "Sorry! Invalid attendance Id";
                btnUpdate.Enabled = false;
            }
            dr.Close();
        }
```

Comment: you are not setting any value for @Now in your list of sql params

Answer (score 0):

For some reason you have double `@` symbol before `HostId`. Change every `@@HostId` to `@HostId`.

And for adding parameters you can use no `@` symbol before parameter name

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("RecordID", txtRecordID.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("HostID", "Int");
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Now", DateTime.Now);
```

Comment: the sqldatasource has a @@HostID in it too. If I change it to HostID the error shows "Invalid column name 'HostID'. Invalid column name 'HostID'. "

Comment: the @@HostID is from the environment, probably a cookie or web service